# how to retrieve the result of a command telnet python

Tags: python-2.7

This is my code with telnetlib :

```
HOST = "@ip"
user = "Hichem"
password = "Hichem"
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.read_until("Connexion : ")
tn.write(user+ '\r\n')
if password:
    tn.read_until("Mot de passe de Hichem : ")
    tn.write(password+ '\r\n')
```

Okay. I accessed to the Server with successfully.

I want to get the result of a command in a file (Restrictions.txt).

The result is:

```
(Number of results = 1)






---    END


LST IOR:,LP=1,D=K'189159;





+++    KOUBA        2016-03-27 09:22:56+01:00


O&M    #617392


%%LST IOR:,LP=1,D=K'189159;%%


RETCODE = 0  Operation succeeded






ESL/EDCN call-in and call-out authority


---------------------------------------


 Subscriber number  =  189159


      Local DN set  =  1


Call-out authority  =  Intra-office


                    =  Local


                    =  Local toll


                    =  National toll


                    =  International toll


                    =  Intra-Centrex


                    =  Outgoing Centrex


                    =  Intra-office national toll


                    =  Intra-office international toll


                    =  Intra-centrex local toll


                    =  Intra-centrex national toll


                    =  Intra-centrex international toll


                    =  Intra-office local toll


                    =  Customize call-out authority 1


                    =  Customize call-out authority 2


                    =  Customize call-out authority 3


                    =  Customize call-out authority 4


                    =  Customize call-out authority 7


                    =  Customize call-out authority 9


                    =  Customize call-out authority 10


                    =  Customize call-out authority 11


                    =  Customize call-out authority 12


                    =  Customize call-out authority 13


                    =  Customize call-out authority 14


                    =  Customize call-out authority 15


                    =  Customize call-out authority 16


 Call-in authority  =  Intra-office


                    =  Local


                    =  Local toll


                    =  National toll


                    =  International toll


                    =  Intra-Centrex


                    =  Incoming Centrex


                    =  Intra-office national toll


                    =  Intra-office international toll


                    =  Intra-centrex local toll


                    =  Intra-centrex national toll


                    =  Intra-centrex international toll


                    =  Intra-office local toll


                    =  Customize call-in authority 1


                    =  Customize call-in authority 2


                    =  Customize call-in authority 3


                    =  Customize call-in authority 4


                    =  Customize call-in authority 5


                    =  Customize call-in authority 6


                    =  Customize call-in authority 7


                    =  Customize call-in authority 8


                    =  Customize call-in authority 9


                    =  Customize call-in authority 10


                    =  Customize call-in authority 11


                    =  Customize call-in authority 12


                    =  Customize call-in authority 13


                    =  Customize call-in authority 14


                    =  Customize call-in authority 15


                    =  Customize call-in authority 16






(Number of results = 1)
```

That's my code:

```
fichier= open ("Restrictions.txt", "w")
while True:
      lign = tn.read_until(b"\n\r")
      #print lign
      fichier.write(lign)

fichier.close()
```

The program is blocked.

thank you in advance.